# Swift: how to set the background image fit my screen?

Tags: swift, colors, background

I set up an image as the background color in order to draw some lines on the image. However now I cannot make the image fit to screen...I'm new with swift.

And I tried set ContentMode of this view to AspectFit,ScaletoFit etc, it didn't affect the display of background color image.

Could anyone help?

Here's the code I used in `UIViewController`:

```
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage (named: "Map"))!)
```

codes for drawing:

```
  class View: UIView {
  func drawRooftopAtTopPointOf(point: CGPoint){

  UIColor.redColor().set()

  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)

  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 140, 100)

  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 140, 50)

  CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

}

Comment: Have you set the `frame` for the `UIImageView`?

Comment: This one was not an `UIImageView` I think, nothing was inside the `ViewContoller`, thus I didn't set the `frame`.  I just set up the background color as an image. If setting `UIImageView` inside, then the lines drawn by CGContext will be covered...I just wanna draw some lines on the image.

Comment: May I ask how to set the frame of this view? Haven't figured it out...

Comment: Every `UIView` has a property [`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame).

Comment: Sorry, would mind to explain more? I'm not CS guys, still not sure with the meaning of property currently...my bad...